# javascript recursive stack overflow

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, stack-overflow

Is there anybody would explain why the result is different below?

```
// test one
function computeMaxCallStackSize() {
    try {
        return computeMaxCallStackSize() + 1;
    } catch (e) {
        return 1;
    }
}

console.log(computeMaxCallStackSize());
```

result is **17958**

```
// test two
    function computeMaxCallStackSize() {
        try {
            return 1 + computeMaxCallStackSize();
        } catch (e) {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    console.log(computeMaxCallStackSize());
```

result is **15714**

When the position of the function 'computeMaxCallStackSize' is different,the result is different too. What's the reason? Thanks very much!

Running environment: 
`node.js v6.9.1`
`OS:Win7`

Comment: probably a bug in an earlier version of v8, on `7.3.0 darwin x64` results are the same.

Comment: Is that true?I think I'll try it later.

Comment: Have you tried flipping the two test cases? Often enough it's not about the code, but whether it was executed first.

Comment: Actually,I tried it on `Linux x86`.I still got different result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not the position but the order of execution which leads to this in the first function the statement

```
 return computeMaxCallStackSize() + 1;
```

calls the increment first and then adds 1

```
return 1 + computeMaxCallStackSize();
```

If you try both return statements as same then it leads to same value. In later one as digit is first the js call stack exceeds overflow sooner as compared to first. The callstack value depends on the order of execution as in 2nd you change the order you get a lower value as recursion happens later.

You can also check by adding some console.log() or local variable call stack will decrease gradually with increase in execution statements.

If you try `computeMaxCallStackSize() + 1;` in both you will get same value.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*calls the increment first and then adds 1*" - **both** snippets do call `computeMaxCallStackSize` first and then add `1` to the value?

Comment: Yes but the execution order differs when you say function is called first that mean the commands on the callable functions are first pushed into stack you can check the order of execution in loupe

Comment: Execution order of what specifically? Which "*commands on the callable functions*" are pushed to the stack exactly? Usually commands aren't pushed to the stack at all, only state is. And what is loupe?

Comment: for  return computeMaxCallStackSize() + 1; the function directly jumps to  recursion leaving behind the addition factor because that would be resolved while returning recursion values whereas in second case it has to store 1 so that when recursion value is resolved it needs to evaluate you can try using njstrace(https://www.npmjs.com/package/njstrace) to check the execution its output is huge i will try to leave an accurate ans soon just putting my observations in order

Comment: Ah, you mean that the second one needs to *evaluate* the expression `1` and also keep its result value on the stack, yeah. Not sure whether the optimiser wouldn't boil that away, though (and it seems that njstrace will affect the possible optimisation).

Comment: Yes it does njstare will reduce the call stack but its clearly can be seen that for 2nd case the  stack fills sooner than first actually i guess this can be well demonstrated via java or c there also it happens same may be thread dump in java can explain this better